# .net quick and secure way of encrypting with printable character result

Tags: .net, encryption

I have a system which is receiving around 15 million records every day (in separate files each file has around 150K records) . the system will convert these files from binary to ascii and then will feed the data into multiple downstream systems .
there is a new requirement now that we have to encrypt one of the fields (lets call it Field A) in each record , fieldA's length is always between 6 to 10 digits .

1.the encryption should be done in a way that the result will only
    contain printable characters

2.the performance is very important here

3.we have other fields in each record which can be used as encryption/decryption keys like date time but there is no guarantee that these other fields are unique (which should not be important).

4.other downstream systems should be able to decode the result using a key (I'm very new to data encryption but I think this key is called private key) .

5.I've read different articles about SALTing , do you think that SALTing can be of any use in our scenario here ?

what do you think is the best encryption algorithm for me to use here ? does .net framework provide implementation of this algorithm ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two separate issues here:

- Choice of an appropriate encryption algorithm for your *security* requirements.
- Representation of the result as a printable string.

The latter is easy: use `Convert.ToBase64String(byte[])`. All the encryption algorithms I know of work in terms of binary data, so you'll need to convert your *input* into binary first (e.g. using `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text)`), then encrypt, then convert back to text using `Convert.ToBase64String`. Decrypting is a matter of using `Convert.FromBase64String`, then applying the decryption binary-to-binary algorithm, then reversing your original conversion (e.g. `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(binary)`).

You haven't really given enough information to determine which encryption algorithm you should use - whether it should be symmetric or asymmetric, for example - but salting is usually involved in one-way hashes, not reversible encryption. A similar concept in terms of *initialization vectors* applies to several encryption algorithms though.

Comment: :thanks for the answer , I think a symmetric algorithm is my best option here because we only have on e system which is doing the encryption . the other reason is that the downstream systems may connect to the sql server and collect encrypted records or will use generated files but in any case we can not create separate record for each system . thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. The result of the encryption is binary data, so you would then convert the data into printable characters, for example using base64.
2. Encryption is not very fast, and one component in making encryption more secure is to make it more complicated so that brute force attacks takes longer to perform. So basically, you have to choose between performance and security. However, as the data that you encrypt is so short, the speed shouldn't be much of a problem.
3. You should not use something that is included in the record as key. The key should be sent separately to the receiver so that it's not easy to come by.
4. There are different methods of [key exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_exchange) that you can use to make sure that both parts have the correct key without anyone else having them.
5. Perhaps, that depends on what encryption you use.

There are encryption algorithms available in the [System.Security.Cryptography namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx), several of them could be used in your scenario.